# Complex regex for .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Assume an image file should be accessed via HTTP with the url `\xy12345.jpg`

And we have a directory structure for image files that looks like this:

```
images/x/y/xy12345/file
```

Where `x` is the first character of the filename, and `y` is the second character.

I need a RewriteRule for the `.htaccess` file and have started with:

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+).jpg images/x/y/$1/file`

I think `$1` is correct for the filename but don't know what to use for `x` and `y` (first and second characters).

If I knew that first was supposed to be actually be 'x' then it would be `^x` but it could be any `A-Za-z0-9-`. So what goes in place of `x` and `y`? Or more generally, how do you get first and second characters without having to match a specific character?

Comment: Try [`images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)\.jpg$` => `images/$1/$2/$3/file`](https://regex101.com/r/uDMyuo/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested capturing groups like this:

```
RewriteRule (([A-Za-z0-9-])([A-Za-z0-9-])[A-Za-z0-9-]+).jpg$ images/$2/$3/$1/file
```

Where `$2` and `$3` captures - respectively - the first two characters, and `$1` catches still the whole filename (`x` and `y` included).

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/lk5aBQ/1).

Comment: The link is a great resource for regex testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with the \1 and captures.  Does this work for you?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9])(.*) images/$1/$2/$3/file
```

I have a little example here in Python which works:

```
text = "xy12345.jpg"
newtext = re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9])(.*)", r"images/\1/\2/\3", text)
print (newtext)
>> images/x/y/12345.jpg
```

Pretty much it's just you need to capture more what you wrote out as a character class and then sub it back in.  This will match exactly one character [a-zA-Z0-9] in that range.  We can adjust that last (.*) depending on if you want the .jpg part or not.